# Macro replacement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, macros

I would like to have something like this

```
condition := case {SOME_VAR}
  when 1 then 'tbl.id = 3 and tbl.code = 6'
  when 2 then 'tbl.id != 4 and tbl.code = 5'
  when 3 then 'tbl.id = 2 and tbl.code != 7'
  else '1 = 1'
end

select
  *
from
  some_table tbl
where
  $condition
;
```

and `$condition` will be replaced with the corresponding SQL code from above the `select` clause, something like a macro replacement. Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: you could run some dynamic sql.

Comment: "Macro" replacement at build time or at run time?

Comment: The conditions contain only static values, so it's enough if the macro is replaced at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  *
from
  some_table tbl
where
  SOME_VAR = 1 and tbl.id = 3 and tbl.code = 6 or
  SOME_VAR = 2 and tbl.id != 4 and tbl.code = 5 or
  SOME_VAR = 3 and tbl.id = 2 and tbl.code != 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Oracle in particular, but in `SQL` in general, well yes and no.

You can't do exactly what you're after, but for the specific case you quote, you *can* do

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table tbl
WHERE tbl.id = CASE {some_var} WHEN 1 THEN 3
                               WHEN 2 THEN 4
                               WHEN 3 THEN 2
                               ELSE tbl.id END
AND tbl.code = CASE {some_var} WHEN 1 THEN 6
                               WHEN 2 THEN 5
                               WHEN 3 THEN 7
                               ELSE tbl.code END
```

Comment: Can't do, since the conditions can be complicated. I edited the original post.

Comment: I was kind of afraid of that :-(